# Fontspec, Sweave and MacTeX 2016: Font shape undefined

Tags: fontspec, mactex, sweave

When I compile the following MWE with `xelatex`, compilation goes fine but I get this warning message: `Font shape T1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n undefined(Font) using T1/cmr/m/n instead`. The problem appeared after updating to MacTeX 2016 (the problem shows from terminal, from TeXshop and from TeXstudio 2.11.0), and it doesn't show up if I comment out the Sweave package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

ciao̥ʃ

\end{document}
```

Comment: sweave must be forcing T1 encoding, a bad idea for xetex, can you not swap the order and load sweave first?

Comment: if your sweave.sty is https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave.sty then it looks like you want the `[noae]` option to stop it loading fontenc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's a bad idea also to load `ae`, by the way.

Comment: using the option or switching the order fixed it, if you put it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted!